# PHP counting varibles and redirecting

Tags: php, arrays

I've been scratching my head on the best way to accomplish this.

I'm getting 8 variables from a url:
a=imagine
b=lead
c=champion
d=champion
e=champion
f=champion
g=lead
h=champion

In this example there's 5 "champion" so I'd redirect to my champion page.

I've added them into an array:

`$a = $_GET["a"]; $b = $_GET["b"]; $c = $_GET["c"]; $d = $_GET["d"]; $e = $_GET["e"]; $r = $_GET["r"]; $g = $_GET["g"]; $h = $_GET["h"];`

`$info = array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h); print_r(array_count_values($info));`

and then printed: Array ( [imagine] => 1 [lead] => 2 [champion] => 5 )

Am I doing it right? How can I use those values to redirect to my champion page as that's the highest count?

Comment: Where is the code that is trying to redirect? It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: Just to a page on my site, ie: domain.com/champion. I don't have the PHP code as I'm nito sure what to do with the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree that `array_count_values` is a good tool for this, but you don't need to make a new array with all the `$a`, `$b`, etc. variables. You can just do

```
$info = array_count_values($_GET);
```

After you have that, you can sort the array in descending order and take the first key to find the page you want to redirect to.

```
arsort($info);
$location = key($info);
```

I agree with the other answer that redirecting to a page based on user input is risky, and you should not redirect without first verifying that the location is valid. If you only have a few valid locations, this could be as simple as:

```
if (in_array($location, ['champion', 'lead', 'imagine'])) {
    header("Location: yourdomain/$location");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice and easy solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$list = ['imagine' => 1 ,'lead' => 2, 'champion' => 5 ];

// find the highest count
$highest = max($list);

// check what page it is
foreach($list as $page=>$count){

    // redirect
    if($count === $highest){
        header('Location: ' . $page);
        exit();
    }
    
}
```

Beware that relying on the user input is not safe. I'd also look up a white list for the pages.

Comment: Great answer, max was a good idea!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: You did. That also helped with another thing I had to do!